# VBA not recognizing Japanese characters

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add Japanese date format in comboBox list bit it shows `?` in place of Japanese characters.

Here is how I am adding them

```
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "yyyy/mm/dd", 0
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "yy/mm/dd", 1
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "dd/mm/yyyy", 2
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "dd/mm", 3
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "mm/dd", 4
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "mm/yy", 5
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "yy/mm", 6
DisplayFormat_ComboBox.AddItem "yyyy?mm?dd?", 7
```

the last option in something like this `yyyy年mm月dd日`

Comment: You need to use Unicode Character - ChrW() rather than typing the actual character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as instructed in the comment

```
UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "yyyy" & ChrW(24180) & "mm" & ChrW(26376) & "dd" & ChrW(26376)
```

preview:

[image]

Comment: @AdilWaqar It's 26085 use the following link so that you don't have ask to me, not that I don't want to answer :)
http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ in that page look for the decimal code points after you paste your char in the input box and click convert.

Comment: Hi. What if I need whatever Japanese character to be recognized and shown in VB controls? How should I proceed in this case? Best regards and thanks

Comment: can you explain further?